# Proper way to create object

Tags: javascript, object, coding-style

What's the proper way to create an object (with its "namespaces" and such)?

**1**

```
//Company object
var Microsoft = {};

//Create an employee
Microsoft.employee = function(name) {
   this.name = name;
}
```

or

**2**

```
//Company object
Apple = {

   employee: function(name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

}
```

**OR** another way? Shoot.

Read something about prototypes and such. What's the proper way to do it; benefits and downsides?

Comment: Given these two possibilities, either is fine. You only need to worry about prototypes if you have a constructor function and intend to create more than one object "of a kind".

Comment: @FelixKling Edited my question, if you know of any better way - please share.

Comment: @FelixKling Generally, if you compare each upside along with its downsides, which one you'd recommend to use.

Comment: The two versions you show are to all practical purposes completely identical. Zero difference (you're missing a `var` in #2, though, and a semi-colon on the last line in both examples)

Comment: It's usually "good" practice to make constructors have a capital letter, and use camel casing for normal objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you forgot the `var` for `Apple`. But otherwise these are basically the same thing.

Secondly, in my examples I'm not going to use the attribute `name` since, when dealing with functions, the `name` is an empty string by default. At least in Node.js and Chrome. So I'll use `empName` instead.

In the `Microsoft` example you are making an empty object and then adding an attribute to it after the fact.

In the `Apple` example you are making an object with the attribute right away.

It's really just what makes the most sense to you, and which you prefer. Since they are, more or less, equivalent.

Now, this has nothing to do with prototypes. Here's an example of what you did:

```
var Apple = { 
    employee: function(empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
};

Apple.employee('Hank');
Apple.empName; // 'Hank'
```

And here's how you would do this with an instance (using the `new` operator, and the `prototype`)

```
var Apple = function() {}; // base 'parent'

Apple.prototype.employee = function(empName) {
    this.empName = empName
};

var a = new Apple();
a.employee('Hank');
a.empName; // 'Hank'
Apple.empName; // undefined
```

So `prototype` is used to add attributes to new instances of an object (using 'object' loosely).  Note that to access `employee` in `Apple`, on this second example, you would have to do something like

```
Apple.prototype.employee('Hank'); // doesn't really do much
Apple.empName; // undefined

// but you can call the employee prototype with a bound variable
// you'd do this if you don't want to make an instance of Apple
// but still want to use one of it's prototypes
var obj = {};
Apple.prototype.employee.call(obj, 'Hank');
obj.empName; // 'Hank'

// a practical use of accessing a prototype method is
// when wanting to convert a function's arguments
// to an array. function arguments are like an array,
// but until turned into one they are not completely the same
var func = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0, l = args.length; i < l; i++) {
        sum += args[i];
    }
    return sum;
};

func(1); // 1
func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // 15
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**: Also, don't prototype objects (e.g. `{}` or `Object`). It's not safe to do this. Since, essentially, every variable in JavaScript is an object, then any prototypes you add to them will be available on *all* variables. So if you did `Object.prototype.xyz = 12` then had `var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` and then tried `for(var key in obj) { console.log(key); }` you would result in the following logs: `a`, `b`, `c` and `xyz` ... which you wouldn't want.